# Solving 5 variables Karnaugh map - grouping

Tags: karnaugh-map

I would like to ask about solving Karnaugh maps, especially grouping 5-variables map. I am not sure if I made this good way, so if you could, please let me know what is wrong. It seems to me everything is fine.

Is there any good Karnaugh map solver which work with 5 variables as well?

Here is the map:

[image: Karnaugh map]

Comment: Here is a link to a karnaugh map solver ( http://www.32x8.com/ ) . According to this website, your result equation is wrong

Comment: But what is wrong with it? How should I merge minterms?

Comment: For example, in the blue group, neither C, D or E keep the same value. So what you cannot group them together. As you can see, the resulting blue equation is wrong. A=0, B=1, C=1, D=1 and E=0 must result 1 (from the table) but with your equation, it's 0

Comment: Because of the mirror red line, you cannot take the blue group. You have to split it into 2 groups of two. You can refer to this website ( http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-8/larger-5-6-variable-karnaugh-maps/ )

Comment: The answer should be [C.D'.E' + A'.B.C'.E + A'.B.D.E']

Given that F(4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 20, 28) = 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This answer is correct ?

Your answer is **NOT** correct; This is not the proper way to group a 5 variables K-map

Lets first look why a K-map is not practical for functions with more than 4 variables

The way the K-Map works is by grouping the numbers that their binary representation has a Hamming distance = 1 [Only 1 bit difference]

In the image you posted

[image]

This doesnt seem like the only way to arrange the values of inputs **C**,**D**,**E** since '*011*' is not next to '*111*'. We cant put all the values of a HD=1 of 3-bits on a line [1-D]

Having 2-bits guarantees that you can arrange the values of the 2 inputs in a 1-D [Line] such that all the binary values are surrounded by all the other values of hamming distance = 1 bit, but more than 2 bits require a 2-D or more in order to make sure that all the binary values are surrounded by all the possible values of a hamming distance = 1 bit

Thats why the way you are taking the groups is **not correct**

You might want to check [This PDF](http://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Essdavis/154/5variableKMap.pdf)

### What is the correct answer?

According to my *[Python script](https://trinket.io/python/fbbf7518b8)* which uses [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm), the correct answer is

[image]

### What tools can i use to solve K-Map or to reduce a Boolean equation

1. You can use my python script i provided above [Its a terrible code BUT works]
2. You can use [This tool](http://www.32x8.com/) to solve up to 8 variables K-Map
3. You can use [Logic Friday](http://sontrak.com/)

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to know about grouping and so on, so I will check pdf which you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Can check out this k-map solver. It can solve more than 9-bit k-maps too!!
Minterm and Don't care terms input, and output of SOP, VHDL & Verilog code snippets.

It has a great representation of the matrix too.

https://www.charlie-coleman.com/experiments/kmap/

Answer (score 0):

## Reflection map method

The method you are using to solve kmap is known as the reflection map method. This method consists of two 4x4 grids laid side by side. For this method, on top of the [basic kmap grouping rules](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/minimisation/karrules.html), an additional rule apply:

> If you make a group that lies in both 4x4 grids, then to be valid it must be symmetric about the middle mirror line (red line).

[image]

In the above kmap for example, the green group, which lies in both grids, is valid because it is symmetric about the red line. Similarly, the violet group is valid.

However in your kmap, **the grouping is invalid due to lack of symmetry about red line**.
[image]

## Overlay method

Another way to see why the above grouping is wrong is to use the overlay method for solving kmap. For this method, the equivalent k-map becomes:

[image]

Here we can ignore the right grid because it has no `1`. Now the problem is simply to solve the left kmap which is a 4-variable kmap. From the [basic kmap grouping rules](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/minimisation/karrules.html), we know that **it is not possible to form a single group with all 4 `1`s**. Instead we will need 2 groups each containing two `1`s.

## References

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-8/larger-5-6-variable-karnaugh-maps/