# Solving 5 variables Karnaugh map - grouping with hazard

Tags: karnaugh-map

Welcome, according to topic [Solving 5 variables Karnaugh map - grouping](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/249212/solving-5-variables-karnaugh-map-grouping/249226#249226) I would like to ask you if for this exercise, should I create anti-hazard group? Is it good?

The solver http://www.32x8.com/ which was mentioned does not show anti-hazard groups, so I am not sure if my thinking is good.

[image: karnaugh map with anti hazard group]

Comment: Usually, no. If there are specific circumstances why a hazard may be a problem, yes. One example of the latter may be using teh output of asynchronous logic as a clock signal.

Comment: When minimizing a Boolean equation you dont include the anti-hazard groups since when they are included the Boolean eqn. still can be minimized, you should only include them if you really need them [if you worry about Glitches or you want to build a Lenient device]

Answer (score -1):

In the above sum there is no need to consider the red one as the four 1's are already mapped by blue and green group. So the answer will be:

$$F = C{\overline D}{\overline E}+{\overline A}B{\overline C}E+{\overline A}BD{\overline E}$$